# why npm start giving ELIFECYCLE error reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO1pX.png)when i execute react start command every time error called ELIFECYCLE appears.
i also reinstalled node several times.but still this error appears.
you can see the error screen in this image.

big thank you in advance.

Comment: i did it several times still error appers

Comment: maybe node version cause problem.. could you try installing another node.js version?

Comment: This is my current version details npm - v : 6.14.4
Node -v : 12.16.2

Comment: Can you downgrade node to 10.20.1.. and try?

Comment: Same Error appearing